# Можно полностью отключить возможность открытия шторки уведомлений в моëм приложении?

Tags: aide

Я хочу чтобы в моëм приложении андроид, нельзя было вообще открыть шторку уведомлений (свайпом вниз от верха экрана), потому что не хочу чтобы пользователи могли перейти куда то, к примеру в настройки телефона (Через саму шторку)
Помогите пожалуйста, такое возможно?
Нигде информации не нашëл...

Answer (score 0):

Это можно сделать, используя системные разрешения наложения поверх других приложений. Вы можете создать слой, который будет находиться поверх всего экрана и перехватывать любые события с сенсорного экрана, включая свайпы.